# Nesting If statement into double loop

Tags: vba, excel, loops

I am having trouble with double looping a function which alternates the formatting of my rows.

I know I can do this with a conditional formatting to a range script but, as I am learning to use VBA more and more I figured it'd be good to attempt to use a double loop.

I'm failing to get further.

```
Sub AlternateRowColor2()
Dim lastRow As Long

lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

For Each Cell In Range("A1:A" & lastRow) 
    If Cell.Row Mod 2 = 1 Then 
        Cell.Interior.ColorIndex = 43 
    remove
    End If
Next Cell

End Sub
```

I can get to defining the loops but get lost in the `for` function to use next

```
Sub AlternateRowColors()
Dim I As Integer
Dim P As Integer
Dim lastRow As Long

For I = 1 To 2
For P = 1 To 1
lastRow = Range(P).End(xlDown).Row
For Each Column In Range(I, lastRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for. You need to explicitly increment the for loops. But your question is a little bit unclear

```
Sub AlternateRowColors()
    Dim I As Integer
    Dim P As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Long

    For I = 1 To 2
        For P = 1 To 1
            lastRow = Range(P).End(xlDown).Row
            For Each Column In Range(I, lastRow)
        Next P
    Next I
```

Comment: Can i i still use the For each Cell with this said code?

Comment: @AsimAhmed No. Since you are not using the For Each loop. You would need to use indices from the nested for loops to get a specific range.